# Intersect doesn't give me the range but the Value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the function below to pull the location of certain variables for referencing on another sheet in the active formulas, but sometimes just need the value. If it was giving me the range I could use the same function for both. The intersect method says that it gives you a range, but on a single location it just returns the value.

```
Function TablePull(tableName As String, columnName As String) As Variant
    Dim testVar As Variant
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strWorkingSheetName).Index - 1)
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(tableName)

    TablePull = Application.Intersect(lo.ListRows(1).Range, lo.ListColumns(columnName).Range)
End Function
```

Comment: Change to `Set TablePull `

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare your function as *Range* instead of *Variant*

   ```
   Function TablePull(tableName As String, columnName As String) As Range
   ```
2. use `Set` to set `TablePull` a range

   ```
   Set TablePull = Application.Intersect(lo.ListRows(1).Range, lo.ListColumns(columnName).Range)
   ```

I suggest never to use *Variant* unless you really need to. *Variant* is the worst type to choose and in most cases there is a better solution than using *Variant*. Nevertheless there are some cases where you need to use a *Variant*.